# How might I resize the window of my tkinter program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Here is an example of my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
class gui_programming(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, Page1):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
##number 1
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        c = tk.Canvas(self, bg="red", width=75, height=100)
        c.place(x=0, y=0)
        butt0 = ttk.Button(self, text="Next.",  command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Page1))
        controller.bind("1", lambda x: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        controller.bind("2", lambda x: controller.show_frame(Page1))
        controller.bind("3", lambda x: controller.show_frame(Page2))
class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        lambda x: gui_programming().geometry("75x100+10+10")
        c = tk.Canvas(self, bg="blue", width=300, height=200)
        c.place(x=0, y=0)

app = gui_programming()
app.geometry("75x100+10+10")
app.mainloop()
```

So, how should I go about changing the window that each class appears in from 75x100 to something else, is there a command to resize the window? I would like to be able to resize it for each class.

Comment: The best practice is to use `pack` or `grid` instead of `place`. When you do that, the window will naturally grow (or shrink) to fit all of its contents and you won't have to worry about resizing anything. You can then easily control the size of the frame by changing the size of the inner canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You already resized the app window from its default with

```
app.geometry("75x100+10+10")
```

Repeat this with a different size.

Comment: My intention is to have the window change inside of each class so, because the app is setup below the classes, it cannot be called, so I can't just repeat the .geometry because app is not yet defined

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to always use variables in geometry
e.g

```
w=500
h=500
master.geometry(('{}x{}').format(w,h))
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `geometry` inside `__init__` method:

```
class gui_programming(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.geometry("75x100+10+10")
```